# Javascript setInterval not working

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need to run a javascript function each 10 seconds.

I understand the syntax must work like follow but I am not getting any success:

```
function funcName() {
    alert("test");
}

var func = funcName();
var run = setInterval("func",10000)
```

But this isn't working. Any help?

Comment: It's always a good idea to see what your browser's error console says in these situations.

Comment: Do you know what happens when you pass `"func"` to `setInterval` and what value `func` has? It's always helpful to read [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval).

Comment: Passing a string to `setInterval()` (which is usually a bad idea in the first place) causes it to do an `eval("func")`.  That is essentially the same as a line of javascript like this: `func;` which does nothing.  As a string, you have to actually execute the function like `setInterval("func()", 10000)`, but it's much better to just pass the actual function name like `setInterval(funcName, 10000)` and never force it to use `eval()` in the first place.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

A lot of other answers are focusing on a pattern that does work, but their explanations aren't really very thorough as to why your current code doesn't work.

Your code, for reference:

```
function funcName() {
    alert("test");
}

var func = funcName();
var run = setInterval("func",10000)
```

Let's break this up into chunks. Your function `funcName` is fine. Note that when you call `funcName` (in other words, you run it) you will be alerting `"test"`. But notice that `funcName()` -- the parentheses mean to "call" or "run" the function -- doesn't actually return a value. When a function doesn't have a return value, it defaults to a value known as `undefined`.

When you call a function, you append its argument list to the end in parentheses. When you don't have any arguments to pass the function, you just add empty parentheses, like `funcName()`. But when you want to refer to the function itself, and not call it, you don't need the parentheses because the parentheses indicate to run it.

So, when you say:

```
var func = funcName();
```

You are actually declaring a variable `func` that has a value of `funcName()`. But notice the parentheses. `funcName()` is actually the return value of `funcName`. As I said above, since `funcName` doesn't actually return any value, it defaults to `undefined`. So, in other words, your variable `func` actually will have the value `undefined`.

Then you have this line:

```
var run = setInterval("func",10000)
```

The function `setInterval` takes two arguments. The first is the function to be ran every so often, and the second is the number of milliseconds between each time the function is ran.

However, the first argument really should be a function, not a string. If it is a string, then the JavaScript engine will use `eval` on that string instead. So, in other words, your setInterval is running the following JavaScript code:

```
func
// 10 seconds later....
func
// and so on
```

However, `func` is just a variable (with the value `undefined`, but that's sort of irrelevant). So every ten seconds, the JS engine evaluates the variable `func` and returns `undefined`. But this doesn't really do anything. I mean, it technically is being evaluated every 10 seconds, but you're not going to see any effects from that.

The solution is to give `setInterval` a function to run instead of a string. So, in this case:

```
var run = setInterval(funcName, 10000);
```

Notice that I didn't give it `func`. This is because `func` is **not** a function in your code; it's the value `undefined`, because you assigned it `funcName()`. Like I said above, `funcName()` will call the function `funcName` and return the return value of the function. Since `funcName` doesn't return anything, this defaults to `undefined`. I know I've said that several times now, but it really is a very important concept: when you see `funcName()`, you should think "the return value of `funcName`". When you want to refer to a *function itself*, like a separate entity, you should leave off the parentheses so you don't call it: `funcName`.

So, another solution for your code would be:

```
var func = funcName;
var run = setInterval(func, 10000);
```

However, that's a bit redundant: why use `func` instead of `funcName`?

Or you can stay as true as possible to the original code by modifying two bits:

```
var func = funcName;
var run = setInterval("func()", 10000);
```

In this case, the JS engine will evaluate `func()` every ten seconds. In other words, it will alert `"test"` every ten seconds. However, as the famous phrase goes, [`eval` is evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx), so you should try to avoid it whenever possible.

Another twist on this code is to use an anonymous function. In other words, a function that doesn't have a name -- you just drop it in the code because you don't care what it's called.

```
setInterval(function () {
    alert("test");
}, 10000);
```

In this case, since I don't care what the function is called, I just leave a generic, unnamed (anonymous) function there.

Comment: On the one hand, I might agree: in the intervening 8.5 years I've tried to tighten up my writing. On the other, there are 117 people who have upvoted this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Change `setInterval("func",10000)` to either `setInterval(funcName, 10000)` or `setInterval("funcName()",10000)`. The former is the recommended method.

Answer (score 6):

That's because you should pass a function, not a string:

```
function funcName() {
    alert("test");
}

setInterval(funcName, 10000);
```

Your code has two problems:

- `var func = funcName();` calls the function immediately and assigns the return value.
- Just `"func"` is invalid even if you use the bad and deprecated eval-like syntax of setInterval. It would be `setInterval("func()", 10000)` to call the function eval-like.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
function funcName() {
    alert("test");
}

var run = setInterval(funcName, 10000)
```

Comment: Make sure you put `funcName` not `funcName()` in the setInterval parameter

Answer (score -1):

Btw this didn't work

```
setInterval(function () {
    alert("test");
}, 10000);
```

I had to give a name (whatever you like) to the anonymous function:

```
setInterval(function alertNotification () {
    alert("test");
}, 10000);
```

Comment: That's not true. Anonymous function works.