# Javascript setIntervall does not function

Tags: javascript

I have an simple html document that should load the javascript again in intervall of 1000

so at the end of the document i added:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
 refreshTime(); }
</script>
```

This functions is defined in the js document and goes like this:

```
function refreshTime() {

var a = new Date(); // Now
    var ahours = a.getHours();
    ........
```

and ends with:

```
   }
     refreshTime();
     setInterval(refreshTime, 1000);
```

so that the refreshTime() is out of the function refresh Time() because of the } If you understand what i mean?

So my problem is that this interval does not function, do i have to set the Interval in the Html document? Or at another place?

Comment: What you've shown looks like it should work. Please specify "does not function" and check the console for errors.

Comment: "does not function" is too vague... Is refreshTime() not firing or are you not getting the expected result when calling it?

Comment: the refresh Time is somehow not firing! Sorry for my englisch!

Comment: i mean is it sufficent to only ad the refreshTime() at the end of the document without any function?

Comment: and with this: setTimeout('refreshTime()', 1000); ???

Comment: This post may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779845/javascript-setinterval-not-working

Comment: the thing what is a little bit confussing for me is that when i put the hole code in a <script></script> in the html document it does work! Can somebody explain me why?

Comment: @RobertRozas, that is not the proper way to invoke a function from within setTimeout. Em Sta has actually got that part right.

Comment: It is more reliable to use `setTimeout(code,millisec,lang)`, because of timing problems. Loops can overlap. Better to call once the function and at the end, call `setTimeOut` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have an error within refreshTime that is causing fail.  I ran the following and it worked just fine:

```
function refreshTime() {
    console.log('Time refreshed!');
}
refreshTime();
setInterval(refreshTime, 1000);
```

So, the problem isn't with how you call refreshTime from the setInterval but rather something in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: You have to be right! I mean the refreshTime refreshTime() works! There must be something between! Tomorrow i will talk with my colleague! But so far thanks!