# Call object literal method using setInterval not working

Tags: javascript, object, timer, literals

I'm trying to call a method on an object literal using setInterval and can't get it to work. I know I have some kind of context problem and found several other posts discussing the topic but couldn't find the information I needed to get my code working.

Thank you.

```
var viewModel = {
        displaySomething: function () { console.log('displaying something'); },
        displaySomethingElse: function () { console.log('displaying something else');}
    };

    setInterval(viewModel.displaySomething(), 60000);
    setInterval(viewModel.displaySomethingElse(), 60000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the () out of your function call.

```
setInterval(viewModel.displaySomething, 60000);
```

You can read all about it here 
[Javascript setInterval not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779845/javascript-setinterval-not-working)