# setInterval does not work

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

```js
function checkPrice(afford){
 var z = document.getElementById('man_cost').innerHTML;
 var a = document.getElementById('mouse_cost').innerHTML;
 var b = document.getElementById('farm_cost').innerHTML;
 var c = document.getElementById('factory_cost').innerHTML;
 a = parseInt(a);
 b = parseInt(b);
 c = parseInt(c);
 z = parseInt(z);
 if(afford == 'cannot'){
  if(amount < z){
   document.getElementById('upClick').style.opacity = '.5';
  };
  if(amount < a){
   document.getElementById('upMouse').style.opacity = '.5';
  };
  if(amount < b){
   document.getElementById('upFarm').style.opacity = '.5';
  };
  if(amount < c){
   document.getElementById('upFactory').style.opacity = '.5';
  };
 }else if(afford == 'can'){
  if(amount >= z){
   document.getElementById('upClick').style.opacity = '1';
  };
  if(amount >= a){
   document.getElementById('upMouse').style.opacity = '1';
  };
  if(amount >= b){
   document.getElementById('upFarm').style.opacity = '1';
  };
  if(amount >= c){
   document.getElementById('upFactory').style.opacity = '1';
  };
 };
 return;
};

setInterval(checkPrice('can'),1000);
```

The `setInterval` does not seem to be functioning. The price updates every second, but if the price reaches an affordable amount, the `checkPrice` function does not execute the function and the effects do not take place as they should. However, when i call the `setPrice` after user interaction, it works.

Comment: You need to pass a function, not pass the returned value of a function call unless the returned value is a function.

Comment: Can you post a working sample in https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: @miparnisari http://ac.net.co/projects/clicker/clicker.html

Comment: @slebetman From their webpage they defined it as a global `var amount = 0;`.

Comment: You need execute this code as a isolate piece of code or as a callback of a event?

Comment: `checkPrice` is the function.  `checkPrice('can')` does *not* return a function. Without a function, `setInterval` has nothing to call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript setInterval not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779845/javascript-setinterval-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write it as:

```
setInterval(function(){checkPrice('can')},1000);
```

This is because the first parameter takes a `function`, having `functionName(..)` will give the return value rather than the function itself. *Note* if the function has no parameters it can be written as: `setInterval(checkPrice,1000);`.

Comment: It still does not work. could you check my webpage? http://ac.net.co/projects/clicker/clicker.html

Comment: @JamesCrovo Then the problem is not with `setInterval()`, could you make a minimal example of the problem with a fiddle or snippet? I cannot edit the code on your webpage, nor do I even know what is supposed to be happening for it to work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3mvL4kmb/8/ but in the process of copying and pasting, it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

Your var **amount** at all `if()`  it has not been defined, this may be the cause it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pass a value "on the fly" in the execution, try tu use `bind()`method.

```
function checkPrice(){
    var afford = this.option;

    var z = document.getElementById('man_cost').innerHTML;
    var a = document.getElementById('mouse_cost').innerHTML;
    var b = document.getElementById('farm_cost').innerHTML;
    var c = document.getElementById('factory_cost').innerHTML;
    a = parseInt(a);
    b = parseInt(b);
    c = parseInt(c);
    z = parseInt(z);
    if(afford == 'cannot'){
        if(amount < z){
            document.getElementById('upClick').style.opacity = '.5';
        };
        if(amount < a){
            document.getElementById('upMouse').style.opacity = '.5';
        };
        if(amount < b){
            document.getElementById('upFarm').style.opacity = '.5';
        };
        if(amount < c){
            document.getElementById('upFactory').style.opacity = '.5';
        };
    }else if(afford == 'can'){
        if(amount >= z){
            document.getElementById('upClick').style.opacity = '1';
        };
        if(amount >= a){
            document.getElementById('upMouse').style.opacity = '1';
        };
        if(amount >= b){
            document.getElementById('upFarm').style.opacity = '1';
        };
        if(amount >= c){
            document.getElementById('upFactory').style.opacity = '1';
        };
    };
    return;
};

setInterval(checkPrice.bind({option: 'afford'}),1000);
```